# how to use conn.db.admin().command() on secondary in replica set?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, command, replicaset

Trying to get results of command that I passed in admin command, 
    but it throws me back a MongoError

how to/ where to set rs.slaveOk() using mongoose lib, if its ?

```
conn = mongoose.createConnection(`mongodb://localhost:port`)
cmd = "someCommand"
conn.db.admin().command(cmd, (err, result)=>{
if(err){
console.error(err) 
}
resolve(result)
})
// MongoError: not master and slaveOk=false
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added Read Preference and Replicaset name in Connection String

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#connection-string-options
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-read

```
var options = {
     "db": {
     "readPreference": "secondaryPreferred"
     },
     "replset": {
         "rs_name": "replica_name",
     }
 }

 var connection = 
 mongoose.createConnection(`mongodb://localhost:27030/dbname`, options);
```